# NSXMLParserDelegate compile problem - iPhone SDK 30. vs 4.0

Tags: iphone

My header file is defined like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Warning: NSObject  {
```

In my .m file I do:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
```

This compiles and works just fine under 3.0.

If I try to compile with 4.0 I get this error:

> does not implement the
>   'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol

If I add:

```
@interface Warning: NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>  {
```

It compiles fine with 4.0, but when I try to compile with 3.0 I get:

> error: cannot find protocol
>   declaration for 'NSXMLParserDelegate'

The Foundation framework is found correctly. Adding NSXMLParser.h doesn't help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the library reference documentation, NSXMLParser doesn't require a strict NSXMLParserDelegate implementation :

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id)delegate
- (id)delegate
```

NSXMLParser checks needed delegate methods availability on the fly.

If NSXMLParser was requiring a NSXMLParserDelegate full implementation, the accessors would be :

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<NSXMLParserDelegate>)delegate
- (id<NSXMLParserDelegate>)delegate
```

I guess that's why there is no NSXMLParserDelegate protocol actually defined in the framework.

So, that interface seems correct to me :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Warning: NSObject  {
```

All you have to do is implement the [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) you need for.

Edit :

You could try using preprocessor macros to activate or deactivate the protocol usage declaration :

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_4_0
@interface Warning: NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
#else
@interface Warning: NSObject
#endif
{
   // interface definition ...
```

I didn't try this with 4.0, but it worked on another example between 3.1 and 3.2

Comment: Thanks

I've implemented the delegate methods I need:

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:

Comment: But the compiler still complains under 4.0

Comment: ah got it. Thanks. Still got an issue though. My min version is zero:

minimum version:0.000000

I need to find where it's set.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, don't reply if you don't know the specific of the problem. Defines work during compile time only. The author needs to differentiate this during run-time and make compiler happy too.

Comment: @stoutyhk, ["iOS Deployment Target" in "Build Settings" corresponds to `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617832/run-time-vs-compile-time-iphone-version-check/6625663#6625663).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this with:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_4_0
@protocol NSXMLParserDelegate
@end
#endif
@interface Warning: NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

Just be sure to implement the appropriate methods in your implementation.