# Can i use Base SDK 4.0 for iPad only app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

We are developing an iPad app for which I am trying to use sharekit http://getsharekit.com

I am getting this error if I use the Base SDK 3.2

`Cannot find protocol declaration for NSXMLParserDelegate`

But if I change Base SDK to 4.0 it works fine.

I think its possible to use Base SDK 4.0 when creating Universal apps.

Does anyone knows if apple accepts iPad only apps compiled with Base SDK as 4.0 and target 3.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll work. I'm using them in the same configuration currently, but I've been using NSXMLParserDelegate with 3.2 till too, not really sure why it won't work for you.

Was googling for NSXMLParserDelegate and came across this question - 
[Error Building Project With NSXMLParserDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503723/error-building-project-with-nsxmlparserdelegate)

or

[NSXMLParserDelegate compile problem - iPhone SDK 30. vs 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966475/nsxmlparserdelegate-compile-problem-iphone-sdk-30-vs-4-0)

Maybe this will work?

Comment: I removed NSXMLParserDelegate from FBXMLHandler interface and it works fine now. Thanks